# How to retrieve ID from ComboBox ItemData

Tags: combobox, vb6

I have a table of clients. Each Client has an ID. I'm loading a combobox from SQL Server and only displaying Firstname and LastName. I created this simple select statement.

```
sql= Select ID, FirstName, LastName 
sql =From dbo.tblClients order by LastName
g_rs.open, sql, g_Database
cboNames.AddItem vbNullString
cboNames.ItemData(cboNames.NewIndex) = 0
While Not g_RS.EOF
    cboNames.AddItem g_RS("LastName") & ", " & g_RS("FirstName") & 
    g_RS.MoveNext
Wend
```

My question is in regards to when I actually choose a name from the combo box. How do i know the ID that's assigned to that client.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd cache row ID values in controls that way.  The information could become stale and the ID might be invalid or even be re-assigned to a new table row by the time you try to use it.  You might be better off retaining key values in a Collection or disconnected Recordset unless you have a single-user, single-process application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning the `ItemData` in your loop. Your code should look like:

```
While Not g_RS.EOF
    cboNames.AddItem g_RS("LastName") & ", " & g_RS("FirstName")
    cboNames.ItemData(cboNames.NewIndex) = g_RS("ID")
    g_RS.MoveNext
Wend
```

Then, in other code you can retrieve the ID from the selected item's `ItemData`:

```
Private Sub cboNames_Click()
   Dim selectedID as Integer
   If cboNames.ListIndex > 0 Then
      selectedID = cboNames.ItemData(cboNames.ListIndex)
   End If
End Sub
```